# name:function(parms) - strange way to define a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm looking at the Hello world Cordova application

For some reason, its defining (what looks like) functions like the below

```
 receivedEvent: function(id) {
       // blah
    },
```

I've haven't seen this before in JavaScript and can't find anything else doing functions like this. Can somebody explain is this doing something magically?

is it different to

```
function receivedEvent (id){
//blah
},
```

Comment: The comma after it probably means that the excerpt you are posting is part of an object literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a method definition in an object or class.

```
const object = {
  hiThere: function() {
    console.log('hi')
  }
};
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

There is a more commonly used syntax since ECMAScript 2015 which is the following.

```
const obj = {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers :) glad to help